# Ignore stretch/shrink when using vspace

Tags: spacing

Please forgive me. I am quite the novice when it comes to LaTeX. I've been learning "on the fly" by downloading documents from the web and referring to sites like these to answer my questions. I'm at a total loss here.

In general, my question is how I can disable or otherwise override stretch/shrink on a page. I've tried `\raggedbottom`. thinking that it would leave white space at the bottom of a given page and keep all default text spacing. No such luck. So, then I tried using `\vspace`, thinking surely it would keep it's assigned size. `10pt` would always be `10pt`, right? No such luck. On this site, I read about how vertical shrink/stretch works, but I don't know how or where to "turn it off."

A very simple example:

```
\begin codeblock
   code (multi-colored)
\end codeblock

Paragraph text.....
```

`codeblock` is a custom environment and `code` is the actual code. The words in the `code` are colored based on there function. When I look at the `codeblock` environment, I see no references to stretch or shrink. The problem I'm having is that I always want the same distance after the end of `codeblock` and the start of the next paragraph (currently using `\vspace` to do this), but currently this keeps changing.

I'm having the same trouble with the `tabular` environment. I don't care if the rest of the page shrinks or stretches a small bit (although I want to continue to use `raggedbottom`), but I want the space after a table or code block to be uniform. Any suggestions??? Much appreciated.

Comment: I just found a posting about \textfloatsep and \intextsep. If I don't include a shrink or stretch parameter, will this maintain a fixed vertical size?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's quite difficult to say something without an example of code. It may depend on many different factors.

Comment: Q "... will this maintain a fixed vertical size?" Not having a "glue" (stretchable and/or shrinkable) component will certainly help. Do check also that `\parskip` is a rigid length in your documents -- the default definition (given in `latex.ltx`) is `\parskip=0pt plus 1pt`, i.e., there's some (very slight) stretchability there.

Comment: Perhaps \parskip is defined to have stretchable/shrinkable parts. Redefine it to a fixed amount. There are a lot of other LaTeX dimensions that will need to be "fixed" too, but \parskip can explain the behaviour you saw with your codeblock